# Accessing $rootscope from a Google Map callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having much difficulty accessing the $rootscope of my Angular app from within a 'load' callback for GoogleMap API.
my index.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp">
....

<script>angular libs/controllers etc.</script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
          function initialize() {
              var appscope = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope');
              appscope.$broadcast('MapsLoaded');
           }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Now in my controller JS, I have something like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('map', ['$rootScope', '$scope','$state',
       function($rootScope, $scope, $state){
          .....
        $rootScope.$on('MapsLoaded', function() {
                console.log('map loaded');                    
            });

}
```

However, the controller never receives the event broadcast from the initialize method.
I don't even think angular.injector(['ng']) is correct but if I do angular.injector(['myApp']), I get an error.

I know I am doing this this wrong way but if anyone can take a look and tell me what is wrong or give me a better solution I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of AngularJS directives already written that wrap up the Google Maps code for you have you considered or tried using one of those.  If nothing else they give some good examples of how you can wrap things up.  The code I built on top of had the Google maps code wrapped up in a plain javascript object that was instantiated and used within a directive to access and modify the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function initialize() {
  // access to the injector of a currently running app and get $rootScope 
  var appscope = angular.element('body').injector().get('$rootScope')
  appscope.$broadcast('MapsLoaded');
}
```

In your code, you access to the default injector and instantiate a new $rootScope.
Using angular.element() will get access to the injector of a currently running Angular app and retrieve required service.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks! And yes I agree I need to 'refactor' and put into a directive like shaunhusain mentioned. thanks too for the tip.

Comment: angular.element('body').scope(); should work as well.